# Loading a Shader file string into glShaderSource and failing somehow

Tags: c++, glsl, shader

Hi im getting this very weird error with loading the shader.txt file's string into glShaderSource and the compiling it with glCompileShader.

```
ERROR: 0:14: error(#89) Syntax error ERROR___EOF_IN_COMMENT and
ERROR: 0:14: error(#131) Syntax error: pre-mature EOF parse error
```

this is the shader file string im checking with glGetShaderiv:

```
"#version 330 core\n\nlayout (location = 0) in vec4 position;\n\nuniform mat4 pr_matrix;\nuniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);\nuniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);\n\nvoid main()\n{\n\ngl_Position =  /*pr_matrix *
```

notice that it couldn't copy the whole thing, But i assure you its all correctly writed. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have an unterminated comment. Your string should look like this:

```
"#version 330 core\n\nlayout (location = 0) in vec4 position;\n\nuniform mat4 pr_matrix;\nuniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);\nuniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);\n\nvoid main()\n{\n\ngl_Position = pr_matrix; }"
```

Comment: It wouldn't let me copy the whole string for some reason. :/ The string doesn't end there.

Comment: Copy the whole shader, otherwise it's impossible to debug this.